# NFS won't start after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, nfs

Just upgraded to 20.04 from 18.04 (Lubuntu) on my media server.  Since then, NFS shares are not available.  I can't find any useful and recent info on how to deal with the following.  It appears that the auth-rpcgss-module and rpc-svcgssv services aren't running; nfs-config is no longer active but appears to have completed its task and exited.  These three had white dots next to them in the output of  the list-dependencies command; the others are green.

```
root@vader:~# systemctl list-dependencies nfs-kernel-server
nfs-kernel-server.service
● ├─-.mount
● ├─audio.mount
● ├─auth-rpcgss-module.service
● ├─home.mount
● ├─misc.mount
● ├─mythrec-1.mount
● ├─nfs-config.service
● ├─nfs-idmapd.service
● ├─nfs-mountd.service
● ├─proc-fs-nfsd.mount
● ├─rpc-svcgssd.service
● ├─rpcbind.socket
● ├─system.slice
● ├─video.mount
● ├─video2.mount
● ├─video3.mount
● └─network.target
root@vader:~# systemctl status auth-rpcgss-module.service 
● auth-rpcgss-module.service - Kernel Module supporting RPCSEC_GSS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/auth-rpcgss-module.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
  Condition: start condition failed at Sat 2020-10-24 13:48:02 PDT; 5min ago
             └─ ConditionPathExists=/etc/krb5.keytab was not met

Oct 24 13:28:51 vader systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Kernel Module supporting RPCSEC_GSS being skipped.
Oct 24 13:48:02 vader systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Kernel Module supporting RPCSEC_GSS being skipped.
root@vader:~# systemctl status nfs-config.service 
● nfs-config.service - Preprocess NFS configuration
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-config.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-10-24 13:48:02 PDT; 5min ago
    Process: 11606 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/nfs-utils_env.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 11606 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 24 13:48:02 vader systemd[1]: Starting Preprocess NFS configuration...
Oct 24 13:48:02 vader systemd[1]: nfs-config.service: Succeeded.
Oct 24 13:48:02 vader systemd[1]: Finished Preprocess NFS configuration.
root@vader:~# systemctl status rpc-svcgssd.service 
● rpc-svcgssd.service - RPC security service for NFS server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rpc-svcgssd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
  Condition: start condition failed at Sat 2020-10-24 13:48:02 PDT; 5min ago
             └─ ConditionPathExists=/etc/krb5.keytab was not met

Oct 24 13:25:37 vader systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in RPC security service for NFS server being skipped.
Oct 24 13:28:51 vader systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in RPC security service for NFS server being skipped.
Oct 24 13:29:27 vader systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in RPC security service for NFS server being skipped.
Oct 24 13:48:02 vader systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in RPC security service for NFS server being skipped.
```

Apparently it's a security issue of some sort.  The file /etc/krb5.keytab does not exist.  Is there a parameter in some Kerberos config that I need to change?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl status nfs-server.service`?  I am running a NFS Server that was upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and it works fine.  I don't have a `/etc/krb5.keytab` file.  I do have my mounts specified in the `/etc/exports` file.  The other hosts using `nfs-common` have no problem connecting up to it.  My mount in `/etc/exports` looks like `/media/storage 10.0.0.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)` as mine is open to my entire network.

Comment: Well, I guess we can mark this solved.   I re-installed all of the nfs server packages, rpcbind, etc., rebooted and it seems to be running now.  My mounts are all in /etc/exports, also with the same parameters as yours.  Nfs-server.service is now active.  Sorry for the wasted bandwidth, and thanks for your time.

Comment: Glad you got it working!  =)  You can either delete or you can answer your own question here as it may help others.  Make sure if you answer your own that you put in any details of how you installed the packages, etc.  Who knows, someone might find it very useful.  =)

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  Re-installed all of the nfs packages, rpcbind, etc., rebooted, and the NFS shares are now available.

Comment: Would you care to list what you installed and the commands please my friend? I am going crazy here with the same issue. edit I have tried a sudo apt-get install --reinstall nfs-kernel-server -y
sudo apt-get install --reinstall rpcbind -y